# filter based fields exclusion in tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a pretty simple ModelResource.

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = CUser.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'c_user'
```

the CUser model looks like this:

```
class CUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    ## Some other fields here ##

    phone = models.IntegerField()
    show_contact_info = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Now i want the queryset to include all the users but i want to exclude the `phone` field for users that do not have `show_contact_info` field set to `True`. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      queryset = CUser.objects.all()
      resource_name = 'c_user'

   def dehydrate(self, bundle):
      if not bundle.obj.show_contact_info:
          bundle.data.pop(phone)

       return bundle
```